# Drop terms of overall odd orders of multiple variables

Tags: polynomials

I have the following expression:

> a x + b y + c x^2 + d x y + e y^2 + f x y^2 + g x^2 y + h x^2 y^2 + i x^3 y^2 + 
>    j x^2 y^3,

I would like to discard all terms of odd numbered combined orders -- such as `i x^3 y^2` and `f x y^2`, but not `d x y`.

How do we do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** for the general case where some terms may contain only one of the variables `x` and `y`:

```
ClearAll[deleteOddOrderF]
deleteOddOrderF = Plus @@ Select[MonomialList[#], EvenQ[Total[Exponent[#, {x, y}]]] &] &;

deleteOddOrderF@expr
```

> a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + f x^2 y^2

```
deleteOddOrderF[expr + y^3 + x]
```

> a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + f x^2 y^2

**Original answer:**

```
expr = a*x^2 + b*x*y + e*x^2*y + c*y^2 + d*x*y^2 + f*x^2*y^2 + g*x^3*y^2 + h*x^2*y^3;

expr /. (x^a_.)  (y^b_.) /; OddQ[a + b] :> 0
```

> a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + f x^2 y^2

Comment: Your code does not seem to deal with the case when not all variables appear. For example the term `expr = x y z` is not filtered out by `expr /. 
 (x^a_.)  (y^b_.) (z^c_.) (w^d_.) /; OddQ[a + b + c + d] :> 0`.

Comment: @Rethliopuks, I hope this is fixed in the update. Original answer deals  only with the case where both variables appear in each term.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nasty trick:

```
deleteOddOrder[expr_] := (
    Expand[expr/.{x->orderCounter x,y->orderCounter y}]/. orderCounter^k_ /; OddQ[k] -> 0
  ) /. orderCounter -> 1
```

It simply multiplies `x` and `y` by a common variable and then deletes this variable if it's of odd order.

```
deleteOddOrder[a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + d x y^2 + e x^2 y + f x^2 y^2 + g x^3 y^2 +  h x^2 y^3]
(* result: a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + f x^2 y^2*)
```

Comment: Perhaps using `orderCounter^k_.`; otherwise  `deleteOddOrder[x+y]` gives `x+y`.